# Help with a kinda recreational/practical math problem

Tags: combinatorics

So, I'm designing a sports league, with four conferences A, B, C, and D. In the playoff semifinals, I want them to face one another on a 3-year rotation: A vs B/C vs D, A vs C/D vs B, A vs D/B vs C. The problem is home and away advantage. I can't simply have each conference alternate home and away, because if I did, the same two conferences would either be both home or both away and so could never play each other without breaking the pattern. So, the next best thing is to have each conference have no more than two consecutive home, or away, years. The problem is finding a cycle of a constant number of years, that's the same order of home and away for every conference, AND ensures that each conference plays each of the other three at home equally as often as away. What would be the minimum number of years for which one could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a six-year cycle. Each team will play every other team twice, once at home and once away.
$$
\begin{array}{cc||cc}
Home & Away & Home & Away  \\
\hline
A & B & C & D \\
D & A & B & C \\
A & C & B & D \\
A & D & C & B \\
B & A & D & C \\
C & A & D & B 
\end{array}
$$
Note that this is pretty nice, except for the fact that the pairs of teams which play don't cycle in $3$-year intervals (for example, the gaps between years when $A$ and $B$ play each other alternates between $2$ and $4$). We claim that it's actually impossible to for this to happen without some team playing at home or away 3 times in a row.

First note that it's impossible for every team to alternate home-away each year. Two teams must both begin at home, and if they eventually play each other, one of them must break the cycle. So suppose without loss of generality that $A$ plays at home against $C$ and $D$ in consecutive years. If we want it to be the case that $A$ plays each team once every three years, then $A$ must play $B$ in the year immediately before it plays $C$ at home and the year after it plays $D$ at home. To avoid runs of 3 home games, $B$ must be the home team for both of these games. Hence, in any six-year cycle (or smaller), we can't guarantee that each pair of teams meets every three years without a 3-year home or road stretch if every pair of conferences to play at both venues. I suspect there may be a longer cycle if you want this this condition to hold as well.